# Chi-squared test for joint independence of multi-way contingency table

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, independence, joint-distribution

I need to understand if there exists a version of the chi-square test of independence (typically used to test independence of two variables) for a multi-way table.
If I have $n$ units observed on $p$ categorical variables, I can compute the expected frequencies. But then it is possible to compute the chi-square test of independence to test that the $p$ variables are jointly independent?

Please tell me if there exists such test, if it will still be distributed as a chi-square distribution and give me some references.

Comment: *But then it is possible to compute the chi squared test of independence to test that the p variables are jointly independent?*---What do you mean by this statement? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Absolutely. But such a test is not in my experience either especially useful or often used. There are at least two common problems. First, suppose you have variables $x_1, x_2, \dots $ with $k_1, k_2 \dots$ categories. Then your joint table has $\Pi_j k_j$ categories and it's hard to avoid lots of very low expected frequencies. Second, departure from a null hypothesis could arise from many kinds of structure and the test is almost no help at indicating what they are. In fact it is hard to think that overturning independence for any bunch of interesting variables is any kind of goal.

Comment: You might look at log-linear models or multi-way frequency analysis.  There's also the Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel test for 3-way tables.  You might also consider if multinomial logistic regression would better address your goals.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I have already looked, and studied log-linear analysis, multinomial regression and all of the others methods. I am actually really interested in this test even if it has many drawbacks for two reasons, the first is that I am curious to find some theory about it since it seems impossible to find any and second because I will use it just for some exercises and checks that specifically require it and not other models/methods... Can you provide me with some references please? Thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: Theory will be similar to that of the usual 2x2 tables; you can use various statistics with chi-squared approximations (including the usual Pearson chi-squared test and the G test) if your expected values are not low (but to get a large enough sample size to guarantee that you'll have huge sample sizes), or you can construct various exact tests. Of course other tests can be constructed as desired. I'd like to echo all of Nick's comments.